# how to compare two list and subtract single column value in c#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

i m trying to compare two list and update the value in first list.

my code is

i have one list like this

```
        ChitNo   Company   LoadingType    BrandCode   PackingCode     GradeCode       Quantity
           1         A         L             B1          P1              G1              100
           2         B         U             B1          P1              G1              90
           3         C         L             B2          P1              G2              200 
           4         D         L             B1          P1              G1              80
```

i want to do group by BrandCode, Packing, GrandCode and sum of LoadingType "L" quantity for this combination and mins of LoadingType "U" quantity of this combination(BrandCode, PackingCode, GradeCode).

I Excepted output is

```
    Brand           Packing           Grade         Quantity
      B1              P1                G1            90
      B2              P1                G2            200
```

For That i returned Code as

```
       var Loaded = (from d in LoadedList.Where(s => s.LoadingType == "L") group d by new { Brand = d.BrandCode, Packing = d.PackingCode, Grade = d.GradeCode } into g select new { Brand = g.Key.Brand, Packing = g.Key.Packing, Grade = g.Key.Grade, Quantity = g.Sum(e => e.LoadingQty) }).ToList();

       var UnLoaded = (from d in LoadedList.Where(s => s.LoadingType == "U") group d by new { Brand = d.BrandCode, Packing = d.PackingCode, Grade = d.GradeCode } into g select new { Brand = g.Key.Brand, Packing = g.Key.Packing, Grade = g.Key.Grade, Quantity = g.Sum(e => e.LoadingQty) }).ToList();
```

But i dont know to compare it and minus the Quantity please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(var item in LoadedList.Where(r=>r.LoadingType == "U"))
{
    item.Quantity *= -1;
}

var summary = from d in LoadedList
              group d by new { Brand = d.BrandCode, Packing = d.PackingCode, Grade = d.GradeCode } into g 
              select new { Brand = g.Key.Brand, Packing = g.Key.Packing, Grade = g.Key.Grade, Quantity = g.Sum(e => e.LoadingQty) }
```

Comment: if U quantity is minus value then it will wrong value i m right

Answer (score 1):

```
var difference = (from l in Loaded
                  join u in UnLoaded on new { l.Brand, l.Packing, l.Grade }
                                     equals new { u.Brand, u.Packing, u.Grade } into lu
                  from u in lu.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                  select new { Brand = l.Brand, Packing = l.Packing, 
                               Grade = l.Grade, Sum = (l.Sum - u != null ? u.Sum : 0)).ToList();
```

Comment: this is wrong. if unloaded list is not containing the combination of loaded then difference is not getting that row

Comment: this code is showing error as "Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'AnonymousType#1'".